# EventRender renders with wrong position

Tags: css, reactjs, fullcalendar, popover

I'm currently building a calendar with the timeline view to get a list of events per teacher. And I want to have a week view of the timeline without showing any time per day. Basically all event of each teacher of that specific day listed on top of each other. Which works if I don't have any custom rendering. It would look like this:

[Without eventRender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Xpv.png)

But, I would like to have a Popover on hover of each event to show more information so I use custom event render to inject Ant Design Popover. And since I'm using react I use ReactDOM to render my custom event.

My code somewhat looks like:

```
const EventDetail = ({ event, el }) => {
  const content = <div>{event.title}<div>{event.description}</div></div>;

  ReactDOM.render(
  <Popover content={content}>
     {event.title}
  </Popover>,
  el);
};

<FullCalendar 
  {...someOtherProps}
  views={{
          customWeek: {
           type: 'resourceTimeline',
           duration: { weeks: 1 },
           slotDuration: { days: 1 },
          },
   }}
   eventRender={EventDetail} />
```

But for some reason, the positioning of the event somehow got messed up due to improper top position. Also, the height of the column itself isn't tall enough for the amount of events rendered. Which looks like this:

[With eventRender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkn6v.png)

My question is: How can I manage to render the custom events properly? Or how can I wrap my  around the event element?

Update: Added codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-field-f1vrj

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess this is something to do with how your `<Popover` control is rendered. But since you didn't show us what HTML and CSS that produces, its a little difficult to  be sure what's happening.

Comment: The difference between the two are the calculation of top is different. The one without eventRender has top difference of 21px per event whilst the one with eventRender only has 7px difference per event which renders them on top of each other stacked instead of neatly. I tried removing the Popover and just use normal div but it still happens

Comment: If you removed the popover then eventRender wouldn't do anything. If your function was literally just `const EventDetail = ({ event, el }) => { }` then it could not possibly affect anything. I would guess maybe that some CSS is being used for the popover and it has got some generic rules which are also affecting the event elements. But that's just a guess. Like I said, if you show the actual HTML and CSS being used (instead of just the react code which generates it) then it would be easier to diagnose. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more guidance on providing helpful info to us.

Comment: I created a codesandbox for this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-field-f1vrj

For now I commented the eventRender part, but if you include the eventRender part, the events rendered very odd.

I hope this is more clear.

Comment: The sandbox doesn't appear to contain the popover functionality?

Comment: I have updated the code sandbox, but that's what I meant before that it doesn't matter if the Popover is there or not, if I use eventRender, the events rendered stacked on top of each other. Unlike when I dont use eventRender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eventRender={info => {
      info.el.id = `event-${info.event.id}`;
      const content = <div>Description of {info.event.title}</div>;
      setTimeout(() => {
        ReactDOM.render(
          <Popover content={content}>{info.event.title}</Popover>,
          document.getElementById(`event-${info.event.id}`)
        );
      });

      return info.el;
    }}
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-field-f1vrj